# .NET Core 5.0: Obfuscar exited with code 123

Tags: .net-core, obfuscar

My configuration

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<Obfuscator>
    <Var name="InPath" value="$(InPath)" />
    <Var name="OutPath" value="$(InPath)\Obfuscar" />
    <Var name="KeepPublicApi" value="false" />
    <Var name="HidePrivateApi" value="true" />
    <Var name="RenameProperties" value="true" />
    <Var name="RenameEvents" value="true" />
    <Var name="RenameFields" value="true" />
    <Var name="UseUnicodeNames" value="true" />
    <Var name="HideStrings" value="true" />
    <Var name="OptimizeMethods" value="true" />
    <Var name="SuppressIldasm" value="true" />
    <Module file="$(InPath)\*.dll" />
    <Module file="$(InPath)\*.exe" />
</Obfuscator>
```

My Post Build event

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release “$(Obfuscar)” obfuscar.xml
```

Build output

> 2>MYApplication -> D:\MYServer\MYApp\bin\Release\net5.0-windows\MYServer.dll
> 2>The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
> 2>D:\MYServer\MYApp\MYApplication.csproj(23,5): error MSB3073: The command "if Release == Release “C:\Users\VVSCPP.nuget\packages\obfuscar\2.2.31\build..\tools\Obfuscar.Console.exe” obfuscar.xml" exited with code 123.
> 2>Done building project "MYApplication.csproj" -- FAILED.

Comment: https://decoupledlogic.com/2014/02/13/visual-studio-conditional-build-events/ See what typo you made.

Comment: @LexLi Sorry I cannot spot any typo. Can you please let me know?

Answer (score 0):

I have copied the above information from various samples in the net, and seems like many of them made the same mistakes.

1. `$(InPath)` <= VS macro doesn't work in XML file. Have to use a valid path
2. .NET core's EXE cannot, and doesn't need to be obfuscated. Only need to obfuscate DLL
3. The post build even `Release “$(Obfuscar)”` which I have copied from the web, had the double quote in **UNICODE**, must manually typed and change back to **ASCII**